# Flipping two sided coin in Android

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview, android-animation

I am using this Rotate3dAnimation class to create a flipping coin animation which is also moving and scaling. But i can use it only with one image view. By just using startAnimation() method on that image view.

But What i want to do is, to use two sides of a coin so it will look like a real coin with two different sides is flipping. Can someone help me about how to do that?

Thanks

```
    package com.example.movingcoin;



    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.Transformation;
    import android.graphics.Camera;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;

    /**
     * An animation that rotates the view on the Y axis between two specified angles.
     * This animation also adds a translation on the Z axis (depth) to improve the effect.
     */
    public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
    private final float mFromDegrees;
    private final float mToDegrees;
    private final float mCenterX;
    private final float mCenterY;
    private final float mDepthZ;
    private final boolean mReverse;
    private Camera mCamera;

    /**
     * Creates a new 3D rotation on the Y axis. The rotation is defined by its
     * start angle and its end angle. Both angles are in degrees. The rotation
     * is performed around a center point on the 2D space, definied by a pair
     * of X and Y coordinates, called centerX and centerY. When the animation
     * starts, a translation on the Z axis (depth) is performed. The length
     * of the translation can be specified, as well as whether the translation
     * should be reversed in time.
     *
     * @param fromDegrees the start angle of the 3D rotation
     * @param toDegrees the end angle of the 3D rotation
     * @param centerX the X center of the 3D rotation
     * @param centerY the Y center of the 3D rotation
     * @param reverse true if the translation should be reversed, false otherwise
     */
    public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees,
            float centerX, float centerY, float depthZ, boolean reverse) {
        mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
        mToDegrees = toDegrees;
        mCenterX = centerX;
        mCenterY = centerY;
        mDepthZ = depthZ;
        mReverse = reverse;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
        float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

        final float centerX = mCenterX;
        final float centerY = mCenterY;
        final Camera camera = mCamera;

        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        camera.save();
        if (mReverse) {
            camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
        }

//        camera.rotateY(degrees);
        camera.rotateX(degrees);

        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        camera.restore();

        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening with this transformation - how does the back side of the coin look like - is it the mirrored image of the front side?

Comment: yes, its the mirrored version of the image from X axis

Comment: Can it be done like that: If you apply the transformations to the second image (the tails side, if we consider the current one as the heads side) and change the visibility of those two at different points it might do trick - huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

faced the same problem few days ago, found the solution in class FlipAnimator that you can find here: [FlipAnimatorClass](https://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/FlipAnimatorExample/src/com/beanie/examples/animation/FlipAnimator/FlipAnimator.java)

it is pretty easy, actually: you just have to pass to FlipAnimator the two sides of the coin. The class is pretty easy to understand, I think, and it is practically doing what g00dy suggested in his comment above.

Comment: Link no longer takes you directly to source code because it's been archived,  you must download the source and navigate under `androidwidgets/trunk/FlipAnimatorExample/src/com/beanie/examples/animation/FlipAnimator/FlipAnimator.java`

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to rotate your view twice !
once from normal position to middle, change your view (eg. change the image of your coin) and then rotate it back from middle to normal.

you should do all the changes in view and starting rotation from middle to normal in the onAnimationEnd in AnimationListener of the first animation !

like this:

```
firstAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        findViewById(R.id.conceptsLay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.factBaseLay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        secondAnimation.startAnimation();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
```

in the code above, I first rotate the conceptsLay to middle, where its basically invisible, then make it GONE and make the other examples view VISIBILE and start its animation from middle to normal!
so what the user sees is that the view is flipped !
needles to say that, first you will rotate it from 0 to 90, and then in secondAnimation, you will rotate it -90 to 0 !

also for making it smoother I've added some alpha animations as well!
hope it will help